# How to save breakeline in DataBase and show it in textarea winform c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I save a long string in the DB, and I whant to show it in a Text-Area in my winForm.

But I do not get the result I want.

The code:

```
insert into table
(
 Description
)
'ערך אחד: ' + convert(NVARCHAR, t1.MonthlyReturnAmount) +'\r\n'+
' ערך שני: ' + convert(NVARCHAR, t1.LastPaymentDate) +'\r\n'+
' ערך שלישי: ' + case WHEN t2.IsActive=0 then 'לא' else 'כן' END
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.filed
```

In the DB:

[image]

And in the Text-Area:

[image]

And it no a breakline, why??

Comment: Post code instead of images.

Comment: It *does* have linebreaks.  You're not rendering them, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is for SQL Server you can use the [`nchar()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/nchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to get the characters number 13, a carriage return and 10, a new line.

```
insert into table
(
 Description
)
'ערך אחד: ' + convert(NVARCHAR, t1.MonthlyReturnAmount) + nchar(13) + nchar(10) +
' ערך שני: ' + convert(NVARCHAR, t1.LastPaymentDate) + nchar(13) + nchar(10) +
' ערך שלישי: ' + case WHEN t2.IsActive=0 then 'לא' else 'כן' END
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.filed
```

Comment: what is `\b`? How can I know it?

Comment: @Ayal: `\b` is 8. [Google knows, ask it](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+list+of+escape+sequences) ;).

Answer (score 0):

Because they aren't rendered as such.

Replace `\r\n` in you code with `Environment.NewLine`.